# Add multiple user id's to one record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a database with a movie table in it,

```
create_table "movies", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "release_date"
  t.string   "image"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  t.string   "movie_id"
end
```

At the moment when a user adds a new movie to his watchlist a new record is create, even if that movie is allready in the database.

So for example 3 users all add the new Star Wars movie to their watchlist, my database will have 3 different records of that Star Wars movie and with 3 different user id's.

What I'm looking for is a way to check if a movie already exists in my database, if so only add the user id to the user id column of that movie record. So that users share the movie record.

Also on removal users should not remove the whole record, but only their user id from the user id column of that movie record.

I'm using Angular so this is my addMovie function in my controller,

```
    movieAdd.add()
      .then(function(response){
        $scope.movieListID = response;
        console.log ('Not empty' + $scope.movieListID)

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.movieListID.releases.countries.length; i++) {
          var release = $scope.movieListID.releases.countries[i];
          if (release['iso_3166_1'] == 'NL') {
              releaseNL = release;
          }
        }

        if(typeof releaseNL === 'undefined'){
          // With release date

          Notification($scope.movieListID.original_title + ' is toegevoegd, maar heeft nog geen Nederlandse premiere datum.');

          createMovie.create({
            title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
            release_date:   $scope.movieListID.release_date,
            image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
            movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id
          }).then(init);

        } else {
          Notification.success($scope.movieListID.original_title + ' is toegevoegd.');

          createMovie.create({
            title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
            release_date:   releaseNL.release_date,
            image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
            movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id
          }).then(init);
        };

      })
      .catch(function(response) {
        console.log ('No search response')
      });

  }
```

And this is the RoR controller,

```
def create
  respond_with Movie.create(movie_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a relational DB, such as PostgreSQL or MySQL, it is a good practise in your case to have 3 tables: `movies`, `users` and the third one which is for storing links between movies and users. This type of association is called `many-to-many`. This will eliminate the duplication of the `movies` records in the DB.

```
create_table "movies" do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  ....
  # no user_id column
end

create_table "users" do |t|
  t.string   "name" # for example
  ...
end

create_table "movies_users" do |t|
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.integer "movie_id"
end
```

In this case, if a user wants to share a movie then one `movies_users` record is created which connects the user with the movie.

I didn't answer your question, but I highly recommend you to think of what I said.

You can read more about associations here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

**Edited (added controller action example):**

```
def create
   movie = Movie.create(movie_params)
   current_user.movies << movie
   ...
end
```

or like this:

```
def create
   current_user.movies.create(movie_params)
   ...
end
```

In both cases the third table record (movies_users) will be created automatically.

Comment: I'm trying to use this method, but I'm having trouble setting up the controllers. How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Edited the answer, added controller examples.